# DEM plot with matplotlib is too slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, geotiff

I made a surface plot with matplotlib, mplot3d and gdal. Here is the code:

```
import gdal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# maido is the name of a mountain
# tipe is the name of a french school project

# 1) opening maido geotiff as an array
maido = gdal.Open('dem_maido_tipe.tif')
dem_maido = maido.ReadAsArray()

# 2) transformation of coordinates
columns = maido.RasterXSize
rows = maido.RasterYSize
gt = maido.GetGeoTransform()

x = (columns * gt[1]) + gt[0]
y = (rows * gt[5]) + gt[3]

X = np.arange(gt[0], x, gt[1])
Y = np.arange(gt[3], y, gt[5])

# 3) creation of a simple grid without interpolation
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# 4) deleting the "no data" values

# delete the last column
dem_maido = np.delete(dem_maido, len(dem_maido)-1, axis = 0)
X = np.delete(X, len(X)-1, axis = 0)
Y = np.delete(Y, len(Y)-1, axis = 0)

# delete the last row
dem_maido = np.delete(dem_maido, len(dem_maido[0])-1, axis = 1)
X = np.delete(X, len(X[0])-1, axis = 1)
Y = np.delete(Y, len(Y[0])-1, axis = 1)

# 5) plot the raster
fig, axes = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
surf = axes.plot_surface(X, Y, dem_maido, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.gist_earth,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.colorbar(surf)  # adding the colobar on the right

plt.show()
```

Here is the GeoTiff file that I used (it is uploaded on my own google account don't worry): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7P95aWmH4DUQk9SbzhNUVNINGs/view

And here is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvFed.png

I am happy with the result but when I try to move it, it takes to much time.

What can I do to make it faster ?

Comment: On a wild guess: You have a roughly 600x1000 cells surface. I am not sure how optimized the mplot3d viewer is (but I have some doubts) but it may likely be too much. Try resampling your data. Or look into more advanced 3d visualization toolkits. Also, what machine are you using?

Comment: For that amount of data I saw that even if I try to make matplotlib slower, it will never be enough so now I am using mayavi and it works :)